# How to save a contact using Cordova to the iOS address book that contains an image?

Tags: image, cordova, contacts

How can I use the contacts plugin to save a contact that contains an image on iOS? It doesn't seem like there's any documentation on this. I know that contact images are retrieved through the temporary storage on the device, but I don't know how to export those images or how to save normal images to that format